# PC8 / CP437 character set with filereader in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, character-encoding, filereader

anyone knows if it is possible to get the FileReader API in chrome to read a file with the CP437 character set? Is there a place where I can list the available encodings?
Currently, my workaround is to read it with CP1251 `reader.readAsText(file, 'CP1251')` and manually replace special characters, which is not cool!
Is there other browsers which support this character set? Or do you have any better idea at a workaround?

Edit: The file is parsed only in the browser, there is no backend available.

regards Oskar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. CP437 isn't implemented (in Chrome and Firefox at least).

Work around to convert to UTF-8 that requires `ArrayBuffer` support in the browser:

```
var Cp437Helper = function () {
    var cp437map = [
        '\u0000', '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u0004', '\u0005', '\u0006',
        '\u0007', '\u0008', '\u0009', '\u000A', '\u000B', '\u000C', '\u000D', 
        '\u000E', '\u000F', '\u0010', '\u0011', '\u0012', '\u0013', '\u0014', 
        '\u0015', '\u0016', '\u0017', '\u0018', '\u0019', '\u001A', '\u001B', 
        '\u001C', '\u001D', '\u001E', '\u001F', '\u0020', '\u0021', '\u0022', 
        '\u0023', '\u0024', '\u0025', '\u0026', '\u0027', '\u0028', '\u0029', 
        '\u002A', '\u002B', '\u002C', '\u002D', '\u002E', '\u002F', '\u0030', 
        '\u0031', '\u0032', '\u0033', '\u0034', '\u0035', '\u0036', '\u0037', 
        '\u0038', '\u0039', '\u003A', '\u003B', '\u003C', '\u003D', '\u003E', 
        '\u003F', '\u0040', '\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u0044', '\u0045', 
        '\u0046', '\u0047', '\u0048', '\u0049', '\u004A', '\u004B', '\u004C', 
        '\u004D', '\u004E', '\u004F', '\u0050', '\u0051', '\u0052', '\u0053',
        '\u0054', '\u0055', '\u0056', '\u0057', '\u0058', '\u0059', '\u005A', 
        '\u005B', '\u005C', '\u005D', '\u005E', '\u005F', '\u0060', '\u0061', 
        '\u0062', '\u0063', '\u0064', '\u0065', '\u0066', '\u0067', '\u0068', 
        '\u0069', '\u006A', '\u006B', '\u006C', '\u006D', '\u006E', '\u006F', 
        '\u0070', '\u0071', '\u0072', '\u0073', '\u0074', '\u0075', '\u0076', 
        '\u0077', '\u0078', '\u0079', '\u007A', '\u007B', '\u007C', '\u007D', 
        '\u007E', '\u007F', '\u00C7', '\u00FC', '\u00E9', '\u00E2', '\u00E4', 
        '\u00E0', '\u00E5', '\u00E7', '\u00EA', '\u00EB', '\u00E8', '\u00EF', 
        '\u00EE', '\u00EC', '\u00C4', '\u00C5', '\u00C9', '\u00E6', '\u00C6', 
        '\u00F4', '\u00F6', '\u00F2', '\u00FB', '\u00F9', '\u00FF', '\u00D6', 
        '\u00DC', '\u00A2', '\u00A3', '\u00A5', '\u20A7', '\u0192', '\u00E1', 
        '\u00ED', '\u00F3', '\u00FA', '\u00F1', '\u00D1', '\u00AA', '\u00BA',
        '\u00BF', '\u2310', '\u00AC', '\u00BD', '\u00BC', '\u00A1', '\u00AB', 
        '\u00BB', '\u2591', '\u2592', '\u2593', '\u2502', '\u2524', '\u2561', 
        '\u2562', '\u2556', '\u2555', '\u2563', '\u2551', '\u2557', '\u255D', 
        '\u255C', '\u255B', '\u2510', '\u2514', '\u2534', '\u252C', '\u251C', 
        '\u2500', '\u253C', '\u255E', '\u255F', '\u255A', '\u2554', '\u2569', 
        '\u2566', '\u2560', '\u2550', '\u256C', '\u2567', '\u2568', '\u2564', 
        '\u2565', '\u2559', '\u2558', '\u2552', '\u2553', '\u256B', '\u256A', 
        '\u2518', '\u250C', '\u2588', '\u2584', '\u258C', '\u2590', '\u2580', 
        '\u03B1', '\u00DF', '\u0393', '\u03C0', '\u03A3', '\u03C3', '\u00B5', 
        '\u03C4', '\u03A6', '\u0398', '\u03A9', '\u03B4', '\u221E', '\u03C6', 
        '\u03B5', '\u2229', '\u2261', '\u00B1', '\u2265', '\u2264', '\u2320', 
        '\u2321', '\u00F7', '\u2248', '\u00B0', '\u2219', '\u00B7', '\u221A',
        '\u207F', '\u00B2', '\u25A0', '\u00A0'
    ];

    this.convertToUTF8 = function (buffer) {
        var out = '';
        var view = new DataView(buffer);

        var i ;
        var n = view.byteLength;
        for (i  = 0; i  < n; i ++) {
            var uint = view.getUint8(i);
            if (cp437map[ uint ] == undefined) {
                out += '/' + uint + '/';
            } else {
                out += cp437map[ uint ];
            }
        }
        return out;
    };

    if ( Cp437Helper.prototype._instance == undefined ) {
      Cp437Helper.prototype._instance = this;
    }
    return Cp437Helper.prototype._instance;
};
```

Use the above:

```
var getTextFromCP437File = function ( file ) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var text = Cp437Helper().convertToUTF8(reader.result);
        // do something...
    };
    //reader.readAsText(file, 'cp437');
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};
```